# Testing equality of two or more contingency tables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, logit, discrete-data, contingency-tables

Which options are there to test, whether two contingency tables of the same variables, say $X$ and $Y$, are equal across the levels of a third discrete variable, say $Z$?

I can think of a log-linear model with terms $+X,+Y,+Z,+XY,+YZ,+XZ$. If it is significant against the saturated model, there is evidence of dependence of the contigency table on $Z$. Is this correct?

What other tests are there available for this problem?

Comment: Even if you have a method at hand to check the null of bivariate homogeneity across Z, you can't check equality directly. (No evidence of effect doesn't imply evidence of no effect.)

Comment: But the log-linear model would test whether contidtional homogeneity is to be rejected, doesn't it?